# Why can't I use boost::adaptor::map_values outside a ranged-based loop?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-range, boost-adaptors

I want to use boost's `boost::adaptor::map_values` to construct a vector of all values of a `std::map`. Take this example code [(or try it at Godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/v3qhPdKT7):

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>

std::vector<int> getValueVector(const std::map<int, int> & m)
{
    auto valueRange = boost::adaptors::map_values(m);
    return std::vector<int>(valueRange.begin(), valueRange.end());
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> my_map;
    getValueVector(my_map);
}
```

GCC complains:

```
error: no match for call to '(const boost::range_detail::map_values_forwarder) (const std::map<int, int>&)'
```

All examples and all documentation that I can find only ever use boost adaptors inside statements that accept ranges (like range-based for loops or `boost::copy`), never in statements that need pairs of iterators like `std::vector`'s constructor.

According to GCC, the problem here is that `map_values` is not applicable to `std::map<int, int>`. However, [this is literally the only example given by the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html), so I'm pretty sure that `std::map<int, int>` should be okay for `map_values`.

Whas is amiss here?

P.S.: I know there are a bazillion other ways of elegantly constructing a vector from the values of a map. I want to know why this code does not work. Also, this approach has the added benefit of guaranteed RVO instead of "probably NRVO", which most of the other solutions that I can think of have.

Comment: You don't apply it correctly. I believe it is meant to be something like `m | boost::adaptors::map_values;`

Comment: The documentation states that `m | boost::adaptors::map_values` and `boost::adaptors::map_values(m)` should be equivalent. But indeed, that seems to work. Weird.

Comment: @LukasBarth I think `m | boost::adaptros::map_values` and `boost::adaptors::values(m)` are equivalent. Note the different name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with ranges, but this might be an answer, so I post it as answer.

At the top [they write](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html):

```
Syntax      Code

Pipe        rng | boost::adaptors::map_values
Function    boost::adaptors::values(rng)
```

And indeed when I change your code to this:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> getValueVector(const std::map<int, int> & m)
{
    auto valueRange = boost::adaptors::values(m);
    return std::vector<int>(valueRange.begin(), valueRange.end());
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> my_map{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    auto v = getValueVector(my_map);
    for (const auto& e : v) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

There is the expected [output](https://godbolt.org/z/qGWja5Md7):

```
2 4 6
```

Comment: D'Oh, you are right. The `operator|`-based and the function-call based variants are named differently. Thanks!